# Adobe socket object not working with proxy

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, extendscript

Trying to get Adobe's `Socket` object up and running. I have this code:

```
var reply = "";
var conn = new Socket;

// access Adobe’s home page
if (conn.open("www.adobe.com:80")) 
{
    // send a HTTP GET request
    conn.write ("GET /index.html HTTP/1.0\n\n");
    // and read the server’s reply
    reply = conn.read(999999);
    conn.close();

    alert(reply.toString());
}
else 
{ 
    alert(conn.error);
}
```

And it doesn't work. `conn.error` is fired, so I know the problem is with `conn.open`. This is the error message I get:

[image: Cannot connect to www.adobe.com:80]

Tried a bunch of other sites too; nothing worked. But if I switch `www.adobe.com:80` to `localhost:8080`, everything works as expected.

### EDIT

I've definitely narrowed it down to being a proxy problem. But I don't know what to do about it, if I have to fix in my script or if I have to talk to IT to see about allowing proxy connections.

Here's where I'm at with my code:

```
if (conn.open("proxyserver.com:port")) 
{
    conn.write ("CONNECT www.adobe.com:443 HTTP/1.0\n\n");
    reply = conn.read(999999);
    alert(reply.toString());
}
```

This gets me the following:

[image: HTTP/1.0 200 Connection Established]

But I'm not able to do anything beyond that. I can only do port 443 (https, I think); port 80 doesn't work on any site. I think this is more of a proxy problem than a script problem. When I do port 443 and get a connection, though, I don't know how to do anything with that connection. I tried sending a GET request afterwards and it returned blank.

Comment: Are you sure the `con.open` function takes a string?  I'm not sure about js, but in .net, you can define an object as an http object.  Also, what if you tried adding "http://" to the address?

Comment: @BGM [Here's the documentation](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/scripting/pdfs/javascript_tools_guide.pdf). The samples all take strings. I also tried adding `http://` but it didn't work. The Adobe Socket object seems to be its own unique animal. I edited above to show my progress; I think I'm just having problems with talking through a proxy and my lack of knowledge concerning HTTP requests. I appreciate your interest in this question!

Comment: I saw you have another related question.  Honestly, I don't know enough to solve the problem.  I was just offering a wild guess.  I worked *once* with a socket procedure in php, which uses `fputs`, using each command on a different socket send.  In other words, maybe you could try doing `conn.write("GET...)` one one line, then send `conn.write(CONNECT...)` on another line.  Another thought - maybe you have to login first?

Comment: Is there anything you can do get more detailed information in the connection error report?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your firewall isn't blocking access to your proxy server - the particular port may need to be opened, too.

Or, maybe the proxy is not set up to use port 80?  If port 443 is used, isn't that SSL; do you need a certificate?  It looks like your proxy only accepts SSL connections.

Maybe try with an ipaddress instead of a domain name:  `192.150.14.12:80` is the one the adobe pdf provides.